# pandas style not showing column name

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook

When I use style to format a pandas dataframe in a Jupyter notebook, the name of the columns (`df.columns.name`) is not displayed.
How can I fix this?

**Set up:**

```
import pandas as pd
from IPython.display import HTML, display

df = pd.DataFrame([[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]], columns = [-1,0,1], index=[-1,0,1])
df.index.name = 'A'
df.columns.name = 'B'
```

This is how the data look like:

```
display(df)   # Has name of columns 'B'
```

[image]

Now, I want to add percentage formatting to all columns:

```
display(df.style.format("{:.1%}"))
```

[image]

but I have lost the name of columns!

Comment: I ran exactly the same code above but there was still a B column label in the box above A for the second dataframe with the percentages. It is probably a bug in your version of Jupyter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I try your code, not find your problems, I get this:
[image]

I think you update your pandas or jupyter version will fix it.

Comment: Thanks, I updated notebook to 5.0 and I have the expected behavior.